# How to resize the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I want to resize the Unity launcher. Is that possible?

Answer (score 99):

## 12.04 and later - Unity (3D)

The launcher icon size can be changed from a new option in *System Settings - Appearance*

[image]

You'll see a slide bar which allows you to change the launcher size.

#### Drag left to shrink

> [image: Minimum size 32 pixels]

#### Drag right to expand

> [image: Maximum size 64 pixels]

Comment: I don't have the line that reads "Launcher icon size" although I just upgraded to 12.04 - How come I missed this one?

Comment: if you don't have that line - you are most probably running unity-2d not unity-3d - have a look at this Q&A to confirm: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I had to switch to Unity 3D.

Comment: On 16.04 this can be changed by going to "System Settings->Displays->Scale for menu and title bars".

Answer (score 13):

Install ccsm from the software center .
Now Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `about:config`

Then go to the Experimental tab. In the middle of the page is a slider that allows you to adjust the Launcher icon size from 32 to 64 pixels. You can also control backlighting and attention animations.

Comment: Presumably correct at the time it was written, it is not currently the way to do this. See kelvinafox's answer.

Answer (score 9):

You should install [MyUnity](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/). You can see icon size option.

[image: My Unity]

Just set **"Size"**.

Comment: Is there a way to get the buttons back instead? Plus, I don't really want to install something. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Sorry, that's only way than I know. :(

Answer (score 5):

Using [Ubuntu tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) under tweaks -> unity:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible as of the latest Unity update.

Checkout my answer on [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/29561#29561) for details.