# Which changes can you make in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

will it be possible to edit the panel in unity?

to add and remove apps (weather, date, main-menu, shut-off-button).

the main menü-button would save a lot of space instead of the normal menü-button. same with the shut-off-button. you can turn off the pc with 2 clicks instead of 3 clicks.

will it be possible to change the positions of the panel and the unity-panel? maybe both panels at the bottom.

it would be user-friendly if changes would be possible (individuality).

will there always be a choice between unity and the old desktop design?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can be added/pinned an removed from the launcher.

The panel can't be moved around (by default).

The "Gnome-Classic" desktop will remain available, choose on the login screen.

Comment: thankyou. will it be possible to change the colors of unity? why can't the panel be moved?