# Should my Dash be full screen?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu Natty with the latest updates and the Unity Dash is in full screen. My laptop has a 17" screen with a resolution of 1366 x 768. If this is not the normal behavior I will report it as a bug on Launchpad but I'm not sure of the specifics if anyone could tell me what the specifics are regarding the Dash size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable Unity Dash full-screen mode, just type in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'
```

For more details, see [this post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/quick-tip-enable-full-screen-dash-in-natty-desktop/).

sources:

- [Can't resize maximized lenses in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40682/cant-resize-maximized-lenses-in-unity/40706#40706)
- [How to get Unity dash overlays maximized by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36341/how-to-get-unity-dash-overlays-maximized-by-default/36349#36349)
- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Answer (score 4):

Someone has already posted a bug report about this at launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/732008