# How to get Unity dash overlays maximized by default?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

In Unity, if you open the applications dash or even if you just press the meta key to open the search dash, they always pop out with a default size of something looking 800x600ish. In the lower right hand of the dash is an icon which maximizes the overlay to the whole screen.

Is there a way to get these dash overlays to pop out maximized by default?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dash is designed to open "half-way" for screens that are larger than a standard netbook.  This is called "Desktop" mode.

You can force it to use "netbook" mode through the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Netbook'
```

If you want to reverse this try

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Automatic'
```

or

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'
```

Alternatively, you can install the configuration editor `dconf-editor` from the package `dconf-tools` and do the same the graphical way:

[image]

## for 12.04

For 12.04 and later you can use MyUnity: [image: Install MyUnity]

[image]

---

There is also a rather neat overlooked method...

[image]

Click the *dash maximise* button as shown, followed by the *dash* button itself.  This changes from *desktop* to *netbook* and most importantly the setting is retained when you logout and login.

For other options:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)
- [How to get the Unity dash overlayed not maximized by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59837/how-to-get-the-unity-dash-overlayed-not-maximized-by-default)

Comment: Works a treat, thanks a lot. Why the unity team thinks that I don't want to see as much information as possible if my screen is larger than a stamp is beyond me, but at least now I know how to change it. Also your answer piqued my curiosity and with some digging around (like here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34490/why-the-controversy-about-dconf-and-gconf) I now found out about the gconf/dconf debate which I was so far totally unaware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity 2D (11.10) you can get the maximized dash adding a single line on dash.qml in the 'Connections' block:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/100380/235