# How to get the Unity dash overlayed not maximized by default?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have a problem, I always have the dash Maximazed in full view, and well not like  [image: Ubuntu Dash] Is there a way to get the original one ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dash is designed to open "maximised" for screens that are approximately the size of a standard netbook.  This is called "Netbook" mode.

You can force dash to open "half-way" using  "Desktop" mode through the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'
```

If you want to reverse this try

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Automatic'
```

or

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Netbook'
```

Alternatively, you can install the configuration editor `dconf-editor` from the package `dconf-tools` and do the same the graphical way:

[image]

## for 12.04

For 12.04 and later you can use [MyUnity](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity) [image: Install MyUnity]:

[image]

---

There is also a rather neat overlooked method...

[image]

Click the *dash maximise* button as shown, followed by the *dash* button itself.  This changes from *netbook* to *desktop* and most importantly the setting is retained when you logout and login.

For other options:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

See the linked question:

- [How to get Unity dash overlays maximized by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36341/how-to-get-unity-dash-overlays-maximized-by-default)

Answer (score -1):

When 11.10 comes out you will be able to make it smaller by pressing the `minimize` button, in the left corner. And if you want to maximize it again, do so by pressing the `maximize` button.

Comment: That's be 11.10...