# Can't resize maximized lenses in Unity

Tags: unity, lenses, resize

I'm starting to enjoy every day a bit more and more Unity. But till now I'm looking for an answer to how resize the lenses in Unity. It takes the whole screen and I would like to be able to resize it.

I tried before searching everywhere and theres no answer to how resize it when you get the lens maximized. Already tried to resize the screen to see if I can get this option but without a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Octavien Damien](https://askubuntu.com/users/2732/octavian-damiean) explained here:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

**Configuration Editor (dconf-editor)**

There are also some options you can edit using `dconf-editor` (needs to be installed first by installing [**dconf-tools**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) at **Ubuntu Software Center** or by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)):

1. Open up the `Configuration Editor` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `dconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `Desktop -> Unity` to find the first two options:

   - `form-factor`: The form factor chosen will affect the size of the Dash. *Desktop* uses a fixed sized Dash, *Netbook* will always maximize the Dash to screen size, *Automatic* decides whether to use *Desktop* or *Netbook* based on the screen resolution.
   - `home-expanded`: Whether the home screen of the Dash should be expanded (*Expanded*) or not (*Not Expanded*).

Comment: Thanks so much...it worked liked a charm.
First you have to change the home-expanded to expanded, them you have the option to change from-factor, that in my case, Desktop

Answer (score 0):

desgua's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40682/cant-resize-maximized-lenses-in-unity/40706#40706) has the instructions on how to set the dash size.

Right now there are 2 sizes. Maximized (fullscreen), and Desktop, which is a sort of 1/3 coveredish style you see on many of the screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for edit my answer, I'm at mobile phone so it's difficult to fix the layout and links.