# Can I resize the Unity panel?

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

In 11.04, how do I resize the panel? I right-click, but nothing happens?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in the current version of Unity.

It [is possible to resize the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity).

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for the quick and helpful reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can change Unity Launcher icon size, so it will be smaller / larger, depends on how you want.

Second post in: [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29553/2937)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot right click the unity panel, nor customize it, other than to change the theme.

Comment: Thanks all! I got so used to gnome, I just assumed Unity was the same!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few customization options in the Compiz Settings Manager, including the ability to change icon size, which will, in turn, shrink the size of the panel.