# How to disable autohiding for launcher in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

The launcher appears to slow and disappears to fast how can I disable autohiding behavior of launcher. I use desktop pc

Answer (score 5):

First of all, install the Compizconfig settings manager from Ubuntu Software Center or just run following command: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
Start it under System -> Preferences menu, find “Ubuntu Unity Plugin” and click into its configuration page.

[image]

Then change AutoHide Launcher to: Never

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)