# Launchbar fix position

Tags: 11.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable autohiding for launcher in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37106/how-to-disable-autohiding-for-launcher-in-unity)

I have launchbar which moves when I remove mouse from left side, but I want it to stay there, whether I mouse over there or not?

How can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install and launch the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
2. Select the Ubuntu Unity Plugin
3. Set the Hide Launcher option to *'Never'*

Comment: hey, thanks but how to install & launch this? when i click link, it asks to "choose an application" but nothing listed there.. how to select "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"?