# Is there a way to make the sidebar be out permanently?

Tags: 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable autohiding for launcher in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37106/how-to-disable-autohiding-for-launcher-in-unity)

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 yesterday and as you may know, the sidebar collapses back when one moves the mouse away. Is there a way to make it stay out? As a side question, will some of fx. Firefox get "stuck" under the sidebar the way that is now when I move it out?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Install `CCSM` (compiz manager) and under the Unity tab you can configure the behaviour of the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) Sry for duplicate question. I didn't stumble upon that one in my search.

Comment: Welcome and np, you need to thank Jorge for it ;) all worked out good i presume?

Comment: It works lovely :D