# How can I report key binding bug into launchpad?

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, bug-reporting

I think that setting key bindings in separate applications is bug ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)).

How can I report this bug, if:

1. Pressing "Report bug" in Launchpad sends me to [documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)
2. I don't know what application to report bug against
3. Starting ubuntu-bug as suggested in documentation and choosing "other" don't help also, because ubuntu-bug program just tell me that I should specify pid

Answer (score 1):

### In general

The best way to find out how to report your bug is to search launchpad to see if your bug is already reported. You'll likely find similar bugs and you can look in those to see what package to use. And you have the added advantage of knowing that your bug hasn't yet been reported.

### In your case

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but if there's some problem with F10, maybe [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/689178) is related?

Or is your bug that ubuntu is missing a global keybinding manager? As of 11.10, that manager seems to be the Keyboard settings in System Settings.

Of course, you can also install Compiz Config Settings Manager. And there are some things that it can do and the other cannot. But I think that's simply because ccsm is the advanced version of the tool.