# Disable F1 in terminal

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

I found this

[How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

but it doesn't describe how F1 could be disabled.

Is there a way that I can stop the F1 key from showing help? I do click it many times when I'm tired and when I want to press F2 (save in MC editor)

Comment: Do you want to disable F1 just in terminal ? or in general ?

Comment: I added an answer to the original question that describes how to remove both keybindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using gnome-terminal then you can edit keyboard shortcuts from:

Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts...

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts...]