# How can I prevent Unity from grabbing keybindings (allowing an application to handle them first)?

Tags: unity, configuration, shortcut-keys

Note: the answer I've accepted works correctly in Precise Pangolin (12.04). It does not work correctly in Oneiric Ocelot.

Original text:

I have an application in which I want to use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to access some specific functionality. Unfortunately, Unity in Oneiric Ocelot (11.10) grabs this key combination and shows the launcher. I would like to disable or bypass that behavior, but I have no idea how to accomplish it.

I have read [How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings) and looked around in all the places pointed-out there and elsewhere, in both the CompizConfig Settings Manager and the gconf-editor. Unfortunately, the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> combination is nowhere to be found or disabled. In fact I have successfully prevented Gnome/Compiz from intercepting the keybinding in previous distributions (Lucid Lynx and older).

Can anyone tell me where I can prevent Unity from interpreting my keybindings before my application has a chance to respond to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager) > Ubuntu Unity Plugin it's sitting right there on the Behavior tab

Comment: Are you referring to the 'Key to put keyboard-focus on launcher'? It seems I've already set that one to 'Disabled'. Otherwise, I can't find any mention of <Alt>F1 (on the Behavior tab or elsewhere in the Ubuntu Unity Plugin settings).

Comment: It has been fixed in Precise Pangolin: setting the binding to 'disabled' or something different in ccsm solves the problem.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick, although I had to actually install ccsm.

Comment: There's another place in ccsm where you should disable it: ccsm > Gnome Compatibility > Show Main Menu

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack

edit, as superuser, the following file

```
/usr/share/compiz/unityshell.xml
```

and change

```
    <option name="execute_command" type="key">
           <short>Key to execute a command</short>
           <long>Key to open a folder or execute a command</long>
           <default>&lt;Alt&gt;F2</default>
    </option>
```

to something like:

```
    <option name="execute_command" type="key">
           <short>Key to execute a command</short>
           <long>Key to open a folder or execute a command</long>
           <default>&lt;Super&gt;F2</default>
    </option>
```

Logout and login.