# Blender keyboard binding over written by Unity key bindings

Tags: unity, blender

I am trying to use Blender to do some 3D modelling. And there is Blender shortcut `CTR+ALT+0` is supposed to move the camera to current view. But in unity this shortcut minimizes the current window. Is there anyway to make blender over-write this behaviour somehow?

Comment: Maybe a dublicate to http://askubuntu.com/questions/69256/how-can-i-prevent-unity-from-grabbing-keybindings-allowing-an-application-to-ha

Answer (score 0):

Most of blender's keyboard shortcuts can be modified within it's [input preferences](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Input). You can also Import/Export a collection of Keyboard settings. Blender includes two alternate presets that imitate shortcuts used in 3DSMax and Maya.

It should be quite easy to adjust Blender's shortcuts to prevent it conflicting with unity.

[image]

Comment: Hey, yeah I realize that I can change the blender key-bindings. But I would rather if there is solution where I can over-ride Unity. I prefer to stick to defaults in blender. Just so I don;t get confused in tutorials etc...