# How do I disable the F10 (application menu) keybinding in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: unity, 11.10, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

Identical to: [How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

But these instructions no longer apply to 11.10.  There's no longer a mapping for F10.

I need access to F10 for chrome's javascript debugger.