# Can I disable the F10 key for all apps without CCSM?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

Neither of these answered my question:

[How do I disable the F10 (application menu) keybinding in Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71236/how-do-i-disable-the-f10-application-menu-keybinding-in-ubuntu-11-10)

[How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

The instructions in that thread seem to be specific to Gnome or compizconfig-settings-manager. That application looks a bit dangerous so I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without it. There's a keyboard shortcuts dialog but I couldn't find F10 in there.

This shortcut is colliding with a shortcut in Chrome that is used for debugging. It's pretty annoying that Ubuntu would assume no applications would be using the F10 key. I use at least 3 applications that need that key frequently.

[image: 11.10 screenshot]

I'm using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CCSM is mostly a GUI front-end which writes its values to the gconf database.

You can use `gconf-editor` to edit the compiz unity plugin options:

[image]

As you can see in the image - the F10 key is associated with the panel option located in the gconf path `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/panel_first_menu`

Thus you can change this to another key value - or write the value `Disabled` to disable the F10 key altogether.

If you want to reassign the key, you can use the modifiers in combination to perform multikey shortcuts:

- `<super>` for the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key
- `<alt>` for the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key
- `<shift>` for the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key

For some options you need to logout and login for the changes to take effect.

If you want to reassign/disable from the command line you can use the syntax:

```
gconftool-2 --set '/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/panel_first_menu' --type string 'Disabled'
```

Comment: Doing that does solve the F10 key problem in 12.04.

Comment: in 12.04 this key-value by default is no longer F10 - it is now Alt+F10 so there shouldnt be an issue with F10 itself.

Comment: i installed 12.04 and i cannot get rid of this F10 feature. in gconf-editor it is disabled, the same thing in CompizSetting. On Terminal i disbaled the F10 function as well, but still, a context menu is popping up pressing F10. whats wrong?

Comment: This is a general Q for all apps - there is a bug in 12.04 specifically for the terminal.  There is a good answer that should resolve this: http://askubuntu.com/a/128800/14356