# Disable F10 (opens "file" in different programs)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, configuration

In various programs like IntelliJ and Firefox, when I press F10, it opens the 'File' menu.

I would like to stop that, I need F10 for other stuff.

- It is not in Settings > Keyboard
- I tried [Can I disable the F10 key for all apps without CCSM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103930/can-i-disable-the-f10-key-for-all-apps-without-ccsm), but it does not work (maybe it has changed since 11.10?)
- Not a duplicate of [deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings-in-gnome-terminal), this is not about terminal.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to disable F10 "In various programs like IntelliJ and Firefox", yet without disabling F10 from your keyboard? I think that needs to be configured in each program, right?

Comment: @Quasímodo I have the impression it's an OS level hotkey, because it does the same in multiple programs, and I can't find the binding in IntelliJ at least. But I can't find OS binding either so not 100% sure what is handling it.

Comment: Not at all! The OS simply reports the key presses. It is up to the application what it will do with them. For example, in Midnight Commander F10 quits.

Comment: @Quasímodo I'll have to to try more applications and search their settings. I'm not quite convinced yet, i.e. the first question I linked to doesn't work anymore but seemed to not have been for single applications, right?

Comment: Since I do not use them, I did not know there was a large set of GUI programs which indeed behave that same way on F10, now I know after reading the linked question. They probably rely on the same APIs or something of the sort that standardizes the F10 keypress effect. But do bear in mind it is not the OS that dictates that behavior. That is not an OS task. The OS reports the event. Applications should be free on how to handle the keyboard events.

Comment: F10 is supposed to be the shortcut to the "step" command in firefox debugger, so I supposed the "open file menu" behavior comes from a bad integration with ubuntu...