# Unbinding F10 on a terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have noticed that if I press  <kbd>F10</kbd> when on a terminal, Ubuntu or the terminal opens the `File Menu`.  Is there any way to unbind this?

I don't see any entries with <kbd>F10</kbd> on `System settings` **->** `Keyboard shortcuts`

I want to use function keys in Emacs to debug my code (e.g. <kbd>F10</kbd> triggering gud-step, etc.) when running Emacs **within** a terminal ( `emacs -nw`) but at the moment the terminal seems to be capturing my keys.

#### Update 1:

If I go to **Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts** I can disable the option "Enable the menu short key (F10 by default)".  So I disabled it. **However** , the key <kbd>F10</kbd> is **still** bound to the menu!!

Is there a way to unbind this key other than through the **Edit**-> **Keyboard shortcuts** menu? Perhaps there is a configuration text file under `etc` where I can activate/deactivate keyboard shortcuts?

#### Update 2:

I also followed all the tricks [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings) and they didn't work. `F10` still behaves as an accelerator in the terminal.

This is all on Ubuntu **11.10**

#### Update 3:

Following the suggestions in [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1017546#p1017546) I also tried:

**3.1** Adding the following code to  `~/.gtkrc-2.0`

```
binding "NoKeyboardNavigation" {
        unbind "<shift>F10"
}

class * binding "NoKeyboardNavigation"
```

**3.2** Adding the following code to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
@binding-set NoKeyboardNavigation {
    unbind "<shift>F10"
}

* {
    gtk-key-bindings: NoKeyboardNavigation
}
```

and the problem still persists.

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings menu-accelerator-enabled false

Answer (score 25):

**Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS**

In terminal, hit **Windows (super) key + F10** to open Application menu:

[image]

Click **Preferences**, and untick `Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)`:

[image]

Comment: Also applicable to 18.04.

Comment: And still good in 22.04 :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using gnome-terminal, go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts.  There is an option to unbind <kbd>F10</kbd> from the file menu.  Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option for <kbd>F11</kbd>.  But note that <kbd>F11</kbd> is a system-wide shortcut for full-screen.

**Update:**  Thanks to James Henstridge for pointing out that there *is* an option for <kbd>F11</kbd>, since it appears on the view menu!  Unfortunately OP says this is not working.  I am not able to reboot at the moment to determine if it works on my system.

Ok, I found this:  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1017546#p1017546 .  Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, rebooted the machine, but the key is still bound to the File menu! Really odd, I have just updated my question.

Comment: The F11 key is an application shortcut key, and can be unbound from the dialog box you mentioned (under `View` -> `Full Screen`).

Answer (score 4):

in my case I had to change the contents of `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
   binding "NoKeyboardNavigation" {
          unbind "<shift>F10"
   }

   class "*" binding "NoKeyboardNavigation"
```

Please note the double-quotes around the asterisk in the last line! It took me some time to find out that it has to be quoted. :-)

I hope it helps you,

Comment: for terminator in 12.04 this solution was good only for me. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found that in addition to disabling the <kbd>F10</kbd> menu accelerator key in the `gnome-terminal` preferences, I also needed to unbind it from Unity.

Using the Compiz Configuration Settings Manager, select *Desktop*, then *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*, then in the *General* tab, then disable the *"Key to open the first panel menu*".