# Disabling F10 in Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcuts

Gnome Terminal captures F10 instead of passing it to the shell. I want to disable it. Searching for the problem returned answers that it can be disabled in "Preferences/Shortcuts". However, it doesn't appear to be there for me.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Gnome Terminal 3.18.3.

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/103200/unbinding-f10-on-a-terminal
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/why-does-f10-in-gnome-terminal-open-the-right-click-menu

Comment: How about Preferences -> (the default General tab) -> Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)?

Comment: Nope.  That Menu Accelerator F10 and disabling that option does not do the trick for me when running Debian 11, Gnome-Terminal 3.30.2, and LXDE Display Manager.

Comment: This works in 2023 https://askubuntu.com/a/1490919/1157209