# Maximise window shortcut misbehaves since 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

In 11.10, I used <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> to maximise a window. I've used it so often, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> have become a learned motion when setting up for work.

Since I've upgraded to 12.04, a single press of <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> opens up the File menu. Mashing it a couple of times does eventually maximise the window. It seems something is hogging <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> for a different mapping, yet when I look at System settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts, the only thing mapped to <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> is Maximise Window.

Where else could I look for mapped shortcuts so I can fix this conflict?

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/q/37313/46531

Comment: @Jakob Points 3-4 in the accepted answer helped me solve my issue. Not sure if it's an exact duplicate though - should I remove the question or should I let the Powers That Be decide?