# Unbind F10 in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

The CURRENT Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't seem to allow me to unbind F10. (There are some similar questions that relate to older Ubuntu versions).

This is causing some problems with terminal mode software and games.

I have tried

1) `/desktop/gnome/interface` inside `gconf`

2) "Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts" inside terminal

3) The setting for alt+F10 in Unity Desktop Plugin in CCSM.

None of these can unbind F10 on my 12.04 systems.

If this is a bug, I apologise for asking: I'll go bug report it.

Comment: What does f10 do? (you forgot to include that ;) ) As far as I know on the desktop it is a Nautilus feature to show the default 'create new folder/change desktop background' dialog. But this one does not work if you do not have the desktop active