# Unity - Customize keys (F10, ALT+S)

Tags: unity, 12.04, command-line

Is it possible to customize the default keys like F10 to NOT use a window control? I am a happy Midnight Commander user and would like to be able to quit within mc and not have the window manager take over that key. I already found out how to disable ALT+S to find files.

Disable ALT+S by clicking Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts and uncheck "Enable menu access keys (...)"

I tried (in the same dialog) to uncheck "Enable the menu shortcut key (F10 by default)" but when I press F10 in that same window it comes up with the option to quit as well as a context menu from the window, which is an annoyance.

I like Unity so far but there are a few gotchas like this where I still prefer Gnome Shell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deactivate F1 and F10 keybindings?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to customize the hotkeys is to install `CompizConfig Settings Manager` through the `Ubuntu Software Center`

Upon launching the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` you might go through each plugin and check its hotkey configurations, but there is a `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` in `Desktop` section.

It is worth noting that certain hotkeys may be taken not by `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, but by other plugins, so you might have look into other plugins' configuration as well.