# Disable icon background colors in application switcher (ALT-TAB)

Tags: unity, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I turn off backlight around switcher icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123670/how-i-turn-off-backlight-around-switcher-icons)

When pressing ALT-TAB, the application switcher appears. You can continue pressing TAB to select the icon of the window you want to show. The "cursor" is the icons with a brighter background color, a slight glow around, and the name written below.

PROBLEM: Starting from 12.04, each icon's background has a different color.
So it is difficult to quickly tell which icon is selected, leading to frequent errors.

For instance: selected Terminal icon's background is almost the same color as unselected GEdit icon's background:

[image]

QUESTION: How to disable icon-specific backgrounds in the switcher?

*Note: Icon-specific backgrounds in the launcher [can be disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37707/what-are-the-different-colors-on-the-unity-launcher-icons). This is a different question.*