# Why did the `files` sidebar shortcut bg turned orange?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I has the files shortcut in my sidebar forever, as i opened it it's background always went red, one day as I opened it it's Bg went yellow/orange.

Nothing else seems to have changed except by the bg color.

I`m very curious as i have never seen this happen before and no one I asked so far gave me an answer.
Why did this happen? (14.04)

[image: Original bg color]

[image: New Orangish Bg]

Comment: On my system they all have transparent backgrounds unless they are active (in which case they are highlighted, apparently using a shade of the most predominant colour in the icon)

Comment: I was indeed refering to the active background, for no reason it used to be red and it's now orange, so i guess it is not based on the shade of the most predominant color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of why the colours are the way they are in this Q&A: [What are the different colors on the unity launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37707/what-are-the-different-colors-on-the-unity-launcher-icons), you received an update to the file manager icon itself, so the background changed automatically as well.

If you would want red back: the icons of all applications are located in: `/usr/share/icons` (and its numerous subdirectories).  Just edit all the `system-file-manager.png` files and colour the orange drawer in red and the red background will come back.