# Where is ccsm found on my application menu?

Tags: compiz

My <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> app is screwed and I can't find compiz. How do I start it? (Don't think I'm an idiot just haven't used it and my computer is more than a little screwed up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ccsm` (or `compizconfig-settings-manager`) isn't installed by default in Natty (11.04).

To install it, run the following from a terminal

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Once's that's done, it's `ccsm` from a terminal and `CompizConfig Settings Manager` in the menu (System → Preferences if you're not using Unity yet)

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

Once installed you can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `about:config` to launch ccsm in unity mode, helps if you're used to that muscle memory for Firefox.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Answer (score 0):

Under Unity (once ccsm is installed) you can find it by clicking on the shut-down button top-right, and selecting System Settings from the menu that drops down.  (The location seems counterintuitive at first but I've found it pretty convenient now that I'm used to it.)