# Uniformizing Unity icon background color

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different colors on the unity launcher icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37707/what-are-the-different-colors-on-the-unity-launcher-icons)

Unity automatically colors the background of each icon to resemble the colors of that icon. I find this disorienting and annoying. Is there any way to disable this behavior and attain a uniform icon background coloring (i.e., no background color).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open the "CompizConfig Settings Manager" application
2. Select the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
3. On the "Experimental" tab, you can adjust the backlight mode.  Based on your question, you want "Always Off"

If you don't have CompizConfig installed you can install it via this question:
[Where is ccsm found on my application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37757/where-is-ccsm-found-on-my-application-menu)