# How do you navigate without a Windows key?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys

Some laptops (such as thinkpads) don't have a Windows (super) key. How should users navigate Unity on such computers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ccsm has an option for that

1. Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) (CCSM).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. type `about:config` and press Enter
4. change the "Key to Show the launcher" setting. (Note: Though the option is named to define showing the launcher it really defines the behavior of the key desktop wide.)

All the interaction/shortcuts are now using that key.

[image]

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)