# dconf-editor gone from repositories?

Tags: package-management, repository, dconf

On this post: [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

It mentions several options for Unity that need to be accessed through dconf-editor. I remember when I used Ubuntu Natty beta on Virtualbox, it was there in the repositories... But now I have it installed on my machine for real, and I can't find it in Synaptic! What's more, I looked on packages.ubuntu.com for it as well, and STILL found nothing!

Why was this pulled? Is this a bug? How would I report a bug like that? Etc., etc.

All in all, is there a way to modify these settings still, or will dconf-editor be back in the repositories soon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package name is actually [`dconf-tools`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)