# How can I only show week day and date in my gnome shell clock?

Tags: gnome, command-line, clock, date

I had to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop pc after something went awry while trying to update to 12.10.

Before reinstalling, my clock had the following format:
Wed 13:21:

[image: Wed 13:21]

And now, this is what I see: 13:21 2012-12-19, Wednesdsay:

[image: 13:21 2012-12-19, Wednesdsay]

I can't for the life of me remember how to fix it, plus I don't think I did anything different from my previous install. If I disable the show-date function either from terminal or gnome tweak tool, all I see is the time. What I'd like it to show would simply be Day and Time, like in the first pic.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "Gnome shell clock", I presume that you do not mean Unity's version?

This is what I have on file. Please try it and let us know whether or not it works for you.

You need gconf-editor ("Configuration Editor") installed; if not, please install it first; you can do this from Ubuntu Software Centre.

- Open gconf-editor > apps > panel > applets > clock_screen0 > prefs
  ("clock_screen0" may have a slightly different name).
- format > `custom`
- custom_format > `%a %H:%M`

The date format is the same as described in the date manual (open a terminal and enter `man date`).

The format can also include limited text formatting such as `<span …>` and `<sup>`. Use `%n` for a newline. Here is an example:

```
<sup><span rise="1000" font_desc="Droid Sans 6.5" color="#878787" weight="normal">%a %d %b</span></sup>%n<sub><span rise="6000" font_desc="Droid Sans 7.5" color="#878787" weight="bold">%I:%M %p</span></sub>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I was indeed asking about the Gnome Shell clock and not the Unity one.
When I try opening the gconf-editor, I have no "applets" menu entry under apps>panel. Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Look in D-Conf editor. `com > canonical > appmenu > datetime`
[image]

Install [Dconf](https://askubuntu.com/a/38272/2973)

Comment: Found it, tried changing it as per the below post, but nothing happened. The funny thing that I noticed is that when my screen locks after idling for a little while, the top bar shows the time exactly as I want it. As soon as I unlock it though, it goes back to how it is now.

Comment: Edocentric, did you log out and back in again after making the change?