# Where are unity settings stored?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

I want to dig into the unity application launchers.  Where do these setting reside?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, and this question is NOT answered in the referenced question about configuring Unity. This question is asking where the configuration files for Unity can be found. Please re-open this question.

Comment: [The scale factor setting is stored in dconf here](http://askubuntu.com/a/510476/14601). This might help in finding the other settings storage location.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is discussed fairly thoroughly here
[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)