# How do I get the value of Display -> "Scale for menu and title bars:" from the command line?

Tags: unity

I did a clean clean install of 14.04 and confirmed that Display -> "Scale for menu and title bars:" is set to 1.

However some users of the application I develop report that its set to 0.875 on clean Ubuntu installs.

Main question:
How do I get the value of Display -> "Scale for menu and title bars:"  from the command line? I want my application to be able to check this value and response appropriately. I realize that my application should be scale agnostic, but its not, and in the short term I can't make it so.

Secondary question:
If the default value of Display -> "Scale for menu and title bars:" can be different to 1 on a clean install, what factors effect this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This setting is stored by dconf in `/com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor`.

Use the command

```
dconf watch /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor
```

to watch how it changes when you move the scale. Note that, apparently, the scale factor displayed in the GUI corresponds to exactly 1/8 of this value, e.g., when I set the scale factor, via the GUI, to `1` for my primary display (on `DisplayPort-1`) the value `/com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor` is set to

```
{'DisplayPort-0': 8, 'HDMI-0': 8, 'DVI-1': 8, 'DisplayPort-1': 8}
```

When I set the scale factor to `2` I obtain

```
{'DisplayPort-0': 8, 'HDMI-0': 8, 'DVI-1': 8, 'DisplayPort-1': 16}
```

When I set the scale factor to `0.5` I obtain

```
{'DisplayPort-0': 8, 'HDMI-0': 8, 'DVI-1': 8, 'DisplayPort-1': 4}
```

etc.

This is analogous for the other displays, of course. Do note that this is not one value, but an array of values, keyed with the display identifiers as returned by `xrandr`.

To change the setting via the command line, use something like

```
dconf write /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor "{'DisplayPort-0': 8, 'HDMI-0': 8, 'DVI-1': 8, 'DisplayPort-1': 8}"
```

Comment: This solution saved my life, since I was trying to see what would happen if I dragged it till the end of the thing