# Enable fractional scaling for display in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, display, 19.04

I understand 19.04 enables **experimental** fractional scaling from a couple of resources

- https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/ubuntu-19-04-release-features
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-enable-hidpi-fractional-scaling.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/b1y2uw/fractional_scaling_1904_xorg/

And others for older Ubuntu versions:

- [Enable fractional scaling for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04)

However, when I enable the feature as presented, I get an error that the setting isn't saved:

```
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
GLib-GIO-Message: 12:22:36.852: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

Part of the instructions require rebooting to even get the menu to come up in display.  How can I enable the ability to enable this setting successfully?

Comment: It happened to me that the `gsettings` called is not the one provided by system, but the one provided by `conda/anaconda`. This could be checked by `which gsettings`. If true, then perhaps you could try directly calling `/usr/bin/gsettings` instead?

Comment: Thanks, @taper.  That did it for me.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the `gsettings` you called is not the one provided by the system, but the one provided by, in my case, the `conda/anaconda` python distribution, which is causing the error message. Then, you can try directly calling the system's `/usr/bin/gsettings` instead.

Note, to check the full path to the `gsettings` you called, try `which gsettings`.