# Monitor scaling does not work properly

Tags: kubuntu

I have a laptop and a monitor connected to it. I would like 125% scaling on the lapop and 100% on the monitor. Changing any settings changes the scaling on both monitors. I would like to scale 125% laptop separately. 100% monitor.

[image]

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing the latest recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

There are quite a few posts out there (see list below) that deal successfully with similar cases via `xrandr`.

Try with a command like

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --scale 1.25x1.25 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 2400x1350 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI-0 --primary --scale 1x1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1-1
```

If this doesn't work right away, I suggest you: 1) post a detail of what you get, and 2) tinker a bit with flags, checking the references.
This should be quite close to what works.

If this works, and you want to set it permanently, check [Best place to automatically add mode in xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268678/best-place-to-automatically-add-mode-in-xrandr) and links therein.

**Sources**:

1. [Is it possible to have different DPI configurations for two different screens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens/555812#555812)
2. [xrandr dual-monitor scaling issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891649/xrandr-dual-monitor-scaling-issue)
3. https://superuser.com/questions/522453/xrandr-dpi-on-multihead-linux
4. https://blog.jamiek.it/2015/04/manually-fixing-multiple-screens-with.html
5. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253449/multiple-monitors-hidpi-scaling
6. https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/i1b2d1/x11_scaling_issues_with_multiple_monitors/
7. https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3606
8. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1857383
9. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr

Comment: Unfortunately changing the setting destroys the entire scale of the monitors. A similar situation to choosing in Gui. I'll have to work somehow..

Comment: @Peter - I suggest you post the output of `xrandr` in the OP, and the exact command you used for testing. Then one could try following up.

Comment: I have edited the answer below: not large enought

Answer (score 0):

1. `xrandr`:
   [image: xrandr]
2. `xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --scale 1.25x1.25`:
   [image]

   piotr@piotr-Dell-G15-5510:~$ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --scale 1.25x1.25 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 2400x1350 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI-0 --primary --scale 1x1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1-1
   xrandr: specified screen 2400x1350 not large enough for output HDMI-0 (1920x1080+1920+0)
   xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
   piotr@piotr-Dell-G15-5510:~$
   [image]