# How to set the scaling of the display through command line?

Tags: video, hdmi, display-resolution, scaling

If I use a second monitor on Ubuntu 20.04 and if it has the highes resolution (4K), the 1st screen keeps glitching. I found out after many tries that putting it to 175% of fractional scaling then 200% again will fix this issue, however it returns after the screen sleeps

[image]

So, I'd like a way to change to 175% and then 200% from command line so I can automate this into a script

Answer (score 4):

You could probably handle this with `xrandr`, which is [a more powerful tool than the Screen Resolution GUI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Dynamically_testing_different_resolutions).
See, e.g., [Monitor scaling does not work properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347784/monitor-scaling-does-not-work-properly).

In your case, that would be

```
xrandr --output <out1> --scale 1.0x1.0 --output <out2> --scale 1.75x1.75
xrandr --output <out1> --scale 1.0x1.0 --output <out2> --scale 2.0x2.0
```

Note that you may need to tinker with other flags, e.g. `--primary`, `--mode` `--pos`, `--fb`.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the settings scaling? I tried `xrandr --output <out1> --scale 2.0x2.0 --output <out2> --scale 1.75x1.75` then `xrandr --output <out1> --scale 2.0x2.0 --output <out2> --scale 2.0x2.0` for 200% on first and 175% then 200% on second, but my screen got glitchy and I had to reboot

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs - Yes, see update. You could check the refresh rate, before and after xrandr.

Comment: How do I use `xrandr` to get the current scaling factor?

Answer (score 1):

I found cool script generator for this: [HIDPI-Fixer](https://github.com/alex-spataru/hidpi-fixer):

> This application allows you to create a script that acomplishes the following tasks:

```
- Allow fractional scaling of your display and its components in X11
- The end result looks nicer and is way less buggy than using Wayland
- The generated script is configured to run everytime you log in
- You can also instruct the application to modify the ~/.profile file to correctly scale Qt-based apps (as KDE does)
- Tested on GNOME, Deepin Desktop and KDE (you need to manualy set the scaling factor to 200% in Deepin and KDE)
```

It worked for me.