# How to set the WAYLAND scaling of the display through command line?

Tags: gnome, display, display-resolution, wayland, scaling

The same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350428/how-to-set-the-scaling-of-the-display-through-command-line), but for Wayland. I want to switch between 100% and 175% using command line.

Comment: Ha, I’m curious to see an answer if any ever comes. That’s the problem with Wayland : it’s severely lacking utility programs, and what’s probably even worse, there will never be a method that works universally, since it will depend on the compositor ; one for Mutter, one for Weston, one for Enlightenment, etc. Driver support ? Well, it will depend. Compare this to the X situation, with a unique interface, upon which session managers could be developed without having to worry that much about this or that driver, and I’m really wondering where we’re heading now.

Comment: I understand there are problems with X, but it looks like the consequences of its replacement haven’t been well thought out. We’re currently in a no man’s land, where development of X.org is dead, but at the same time, nothing fully replaces it. The way I see things, either there will be a huge turn back to X, or one, two wayland compositors at the very best, will completely predate the Wayland world, each with their own utilities, mutually incompatible with each other… am I the only one to see a problem here ? That being said, I would like very much to be proven wrong !

Comment: As a consequence, going back to your question, you’re probably more likely to get an answer if you say what compositor you’re using (but I don’t have the answer anyway, after trying Wayland for some time, I came back to X months ago)