How to set “Scale” to “100 %” using command line?
Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on Wayland.
Tried gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1, but that doesn’t work.
I would like to set scale using script vs have user set scale using GUI.


Also asked here, but without answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448179/how-to-set-the-wayland-scaling-of-the-display-through-command-line. The scaling factor of the command you tried controls the scaling of fonts.

Some useful info here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gnome-44-wayland-fractional-scaling-via-terminal/16988/2

It does not appear to be trivial: here, https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/change-scaling-resolution-of-primary-monitor-from-bash-terminal/76778, someone produced a python script.

Thanks for helping out @vanadium… ended up creating ~/.config/monitors.xml file.
