# Chrome keeps opening maximized

Tags: google-chrome, browser, resize, window-management

Chrome opens up in a maximized windows. No matter how many times I resize it down it stays the same on new windows. I tried resizing the windows then quitting Chrome, but still no luck.

If anything is there a way I can manually set the default window size through the shell or something?

Comment: I dont know what kind of OS version you are using. But on my comp it seems to be a damned bug in UBUNTU 11.X. Those dummheads are opening ANY kind of new application window in fullscreen.
:((

Comment: @Alberto Your issue may be related to screensize if it's small enough. You can try adjusting the "Automaximize value" setting in `ccsm` if you're using 11.10: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903

Comment: @WarriorIng64, that solved my problem. No more automaximizing window for Google Chrome ;)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! I think I've discovered why this is happening for me at least.  Oscar, you didn't mention using two screens but I suspect you are (?).  If not, mine may be a separate issue.

When I have a chrome window on my external monitor that is taller than my primary screen and I open a new window, it's full screen on my primary screen.  If I adjust the height making it short enough to fit on my primary screen, it opens as expected.

I suspect any application that creates new windows of a particular size would exhibit the same behavior, I don't know anything else on my computer that does that though.  Maybe Alberto can experiment with this.

Comment: That seems to be the same as for me also! My 'primary' monitor is 1680x1050 but my 'secondary' is 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

How is Chrome being opened?  Specifically, I am curious about the command issued by the launcher.  The reason for my interest is that the '--kiosk' modifier is used to open Chrome in fullscreen mode.  Subsequently, I would check to ensure the '--kiosk' is not in the command line.

Comment: Not sure... I just installed it through the Software Manager then i click on on the dock on the side. Im in 11.04

Comment: Ahhh...so we are not talking about fullscreen so much as we are talking about Chrome starting maximized.  Check to see if the '--start-maximized' startup switch is being called out.

Comment: Try this: Go to Ubuntu Control Center, select Main Menu.  Navigate through the Main Menu utility until you find Chrome.  Then select Chrome and click the properties button.  This will allow you to look at the command line launching Chrome.

Comment: This is what i have there: `/usr/bin/chromium-browser %U`?

Comment: I am not sure what the %U is, but suspect that is not the problem.  Have you tried the suggestion offered up by @daithib8?  Might be worth a shot.  I guess I am curious to know if the CCSM workaround prevents Chrome for ever being maximized.

Answer (score 0):

In compiz settings (`ccsm`) under Window Rules, put class=Chromium-browser in the no_maximize_match field.

Comment: Im at work, and cant test, but will this make it so its _never_ able to maximize?