# How to permanently hide Unity dock?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I like unity, and the way it organizes applications but I don't like the dock. I would like to use Docky instead.

If it's possible, I don't even want to see the dock when I hit the super key. I don't even wanna see it when I open Unity launcher.

While I wish this was all possible, I know this is probably impossible but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is a way to replace the Unity launcher with Docky, but you can always auto-hide it and just ignore it. That seems quite annoying though.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

^That should help you with auto-hiding the launcher.

Alternatively, you can always log into the Ubuntu Classic session, delete the bottom panel, and run Docky at startup. If you need further help with that, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -2):

1. Install advanced Compiz settings manager (type *ccsm* in Software Center).
2. Run it and find Unity plugin under Desktop category.
3. Customize it any way you want. To solve your problem you should set the `Reveal Mode` to `None` and `Hide Launcher` to `Autohide`. You can also disable the `Key to show the launcher` and install `Gnome Do` instead, which many find much better.

Using this manager you're able to customize your Ubuntu very deeply, not just the Unity behaviour. I think you'll be amazed with what you can do with it.

I confirm that this solution still works on 11.10.

Comment: I think you should try your solution before you post it. You'll find that ccsm offers about two settings for customizing Unity. The requested setting is not one of them. Alas, ccsm is not the solution to every problem.

Comment: **Reveal Mode** lets you hide the launcher forever or place it wherever you want. I never said that ccsm is a solution for every problem, but for this one it is! Now who's gotta recheck what he says before arrogantly pointing fingers?

Comment: You need to re-read the question. The dock still still shows up when you hit the super key (or however you launch the launcher), and stuff.

Comment: @Daniel I think it's you who needs to re-read the question and than apologize. Because of your arrogance the correct answer got downrated.