# How to configure workspace layout?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I have moved from Maverick to Oneiric and my workspace configuration changed from one row of five workspaces to two rows of two workspaces each.

It looks like in Oneiric there was a migration for gconf since gconf-editor is not installed.

Is there a way to add or configure workspace layout in Oneiric with Unity?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install the [Compizconfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/compizconfig-settings-manager) with

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Then open it and find the "General Options" page (it should be near the top). One of the tabs should be "Desktop Size". Here you can choose the number of desktops for each row and column.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)