# How to remove shortcut key for Unity , which is "Meta" key on keyboard

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm a big fan of <kbd>Meta</kbd> key , but in Unity interface , by pressing that key , unity's interface will show up , hindered further action with that key , e.g <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Without hacking its source code , anyway to remove that shortcut key ?

Comment: I am still able to use Meta+Tab and other Meta+key shortcuts.

Comment: The trick is hold `Super` then press the other next key. So hold `Super` _then_ press `d` to show desktop. If you try pushing both at once, some weird timing things will happen and you'll usually end up doing both, but probably not in the order you would like, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts can be edited using the compizconfig-settings-manager. You can install it as part of the Ubuntu distribution by typing: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`. The Settings for Keyboard shortcuts are at the Ubuntu-Unity-Plugin-Menu.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: cool , i can also reduce icon size there

Answer (score 0):

Super is used in combination with other keys in Unity. For instance, pressing <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> will launch or focus the first application in your launcher. <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> will display all open windows, <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> will display all your workspaces, super+t opens the thrash, <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> opens the apps lense, <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> opens the files and folders lense and <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> opens the music lense.

Comment: And how can I disable these keys?