# Can you resize Unity launcher?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Is it possible to resize the Unity Launcher in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 7):

Sure. In CCSM, select the Unity plugin, experimental tab.

Here is a video:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/unity-launcher-icon-size-to-be-resizable/

Comment: But ccsm isn't installed by default, so you'll have to `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` first.

Comment: it does not work on Beta 2 - in fact the unit plugin is not active by defualt - it was in 11.04 ??