# How to navigate and launch installed applications?

Tags: unity, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

How do you navigate and select via keyboard installed applications in Unity? Previously, I added a keyboard shortcut to open the "Applications" menu, and then I could quickly navigate to whatever application I need to open. I can find no similar functionality in Unity. I can't even find a listing of installed apps.

The only way I can find to launch an app is to click that "Ubuntu" logo box in the upper-right hand corner, and then type in the applications name to search for it, which is a little cumbersome.

Comment: @jrg, I'm not really asking about keyboard shortcuts. Yes, I could setup a keyboard shortcut to launch a specific app...but that's not practical to do for all apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on the applications button in the dash to get to your application:

[image]

You can get there by hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after you've invoked the dash, or click on the little icon. Or you can get there directly by using the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)