# how to run wine as an independent software?

Tags: wine

Once it has been installed using the command sudo get-apt install wine.
How can I run this software?.Is there any shortcut created such as chromium or VLC or is there any other way to run it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to navigate and launch installed applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66435/how-to-navigate-and-launch-installed-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wine` via terminal

```
wine your_exe
```

with the full path to your exe.

Or also via context menu of your exe file in your file manager.

Installed Windows programs you can start usually via your Dash.

Comment: a process worked out but then nothing happened