# Super key not opening Dash

Tags: unity, 11.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I just cleanly installed Ubuntu 11.10 (with new, clean home folder)

The <kbd>Super</kbd> key no longer calls up the dash. Was this behaviour changed since the previous release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the settings for Unity:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

And double check that the keyboard shortcut for Unity is set:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this would make a difference, or if it is just a coincidence but, using the "Additional Drivers" tool I switched video drivers back to the "recommended current nVidia" and everything works fine.  This problem has plagued a machine for months, and after the switch it is working 100%.