# Holding Super Key doesn't show Unity shortcuts in 14.04?

Tags: shortcuts

When I hold down the superkey the list of keyboard shortcuts no longer appears? How do I enable again?

Answer (score 1):

## Unity Tweak Tool

`Unity` / `Additional` / `Hold Super for keyboard shortcuts`

or via `compizconfig-settings-manager`:

## CompizConfig Settings Manager

`Ubuntu Unity Plugin` / `General` / `Enable Shortcut Hints Overlay`

Answer (score -1):

Check the settings for Unity:

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

And double check that the keyboard shortcut for Unity is set:

[image]

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/68429/280643)