# Unity launcher not triggered with Super key

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher

I just started using my new Dell XPS 13 Developers Eddition with Ubuntu 16.04. I am used to triggering the  Unity Launcher with the <kbd>Super</kbd> / Windows key, and triggering the list of shortcuts by holding that key. However, with the default setup, hitting <kbd>Super</kbd> alone does nothing. In addition, when I try assigning <kbd>Super</kbd> to trigger the Unity launcher from `unity-tweak-tool` it will not let me (though I can assign an trigger it with another key).

Notice that in `unity-tweak-tool`, nothing shows up as the shotcut for "Show the launcher". If I click "Restore defaults" it is the same.

[image]

I have also confirmed that the <kbd>Super</kbd> works fine when paired with other keys.

Is there any way for me to trigger the Unity launcher with <kbd>Super</kbd> as has been the default in t he past? I am also curious why it would not be working out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe Dell changed some things, I'd ask them 1st if the laptop came with Ubuntu.

Otherwise install compizconfig-settings-manager & look in the unity plugin > Launcher, see screen. The x button on far right sets to default which is Super & enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I did this, and removed the `dell-super-key` package based on [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/752102/396191). I am not sure if this solution would have worked without that, or if removing that package would have been enough, but either way, it i s fixed now. I did have to restart in order for it to work though.

Comment: So it looks like Dell did indeed change this. On some slow day  I'd probably call support & inquire as to why..

Comment: I gather from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/758193/396191) that it is actually for legal reasons - I guess not being able to tie the Windows-branded key to an Ubuntu feature? That seems ridiculous,  but is also not at all surprising to unfortunately. As a commenter points out in that thread, it would have been nice if they would have put an Ubuntu logo on the super key like System 76 does, but I guess they couldn't be bothered...