# Super + Space shows numbers on icons on Unity launcher instead of switching between languages

Tags: unity, 18.04, launcher, keyboard-layout, input-language

After I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> started showing numbers on icons on unity launcher instead of switching between languages. How can I fix that?

*Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Switch to next source* is configured to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Can you check is **compizconfig-settings-manager** or **unity-tweak-tool** is installed? In case Yes, you can try found solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846245/unity-launcher-not-triggered-with-super-key

Comment: @S_Flash, thank you, compizconfig was installed and helped. The only weird thing now is that when I switch between 3 languages (which takes about 1 second), keyboard shortcuts menu (hint) pops up. I'm really starting to hate 18.04 :(

Comment: Is no reasons to hate 18.04, because Unity is not native for Ubuntu 18. Now we need focus on GNOME as native shell for Ubuntu 18+. Try search solution with keyboard layout switch delay here: https://askubuntu.com/a/353809/881020 I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/846289/881020

> Install compizconfig-settings-manager & look in the unity
>   plugin > Launcher, see screen. The x button on far right sets to
>   default which is Super & enabled.
>
> [image]