# Input Problems After Upgrading to Ubuntu 18

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, language-support

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 (with Unity GUI) and I have a lot of problems. Most annoyingly is that Super+Space (or Shift+Super+Space) no longer switches the input source (despite being set to these combinations in the settings). "Super" was a key to "show Dash, Launcher and help overlay" before. Disabling this key in CompizConfig launcher panel doesn't change the outcome

Login screen defaulted to Swiss layout (it looks like Swiss or French), for which I don't know location of special symbols used in my passwords.
So I have to use screen keyboard to enter password on login.

My questions are:

1. How do I switch **login** input layout to English? I have "Swiss" layout in "Ctrl-Alt-Fx" consoles too for some mysterious reason. I never set up German or French layouts or UI. Only Russian-Mac and Japanese (ibus which no longer works for me either) layouts.
2. How to get back to "Super+Space" language switch? (if I select Ctrl+Space, it works)

Thank you!

<sub>I've combined these questions, because all of it looks like some config corruption. It's hard to provide screenshots, because LAN no longer works after update as many other crucial things, like NVIDIA</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super + Space shows numbers on icons on Unity launcher instead of switching between languages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093399/super-space-shows-numbers-on-icons-on-unity-launcher-instead-of-switching-betw)

Comment: No, this setting in compiz config launcher panel doesn't affect the outcome, I checked it too

Comment: Are you use GNOME now?

Comment: Sorry, no, Unity. I'll add it to the question

Comment: Unity shows a keyboard icon in the system tray in the top-right corner of the screen. Click that icon, and you will see a list of active layouts plus an option to configure them. In the left part of the configuration window, you see a list of active keyboard layouts. Now click the Options button in the bottom-right corner of the window and select the hotkey to switch between the layouts. **Find key(s) to change layout** and try configure there.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. If I switch it to something, like Ctrl+Space, it works. But I'd like Super+Space (which is set there by default) to work, because on every other machine (mac or windows) I use Super+Space