# Change shortcut <Alt>Right

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

In my 11.04, the `<Alt>Right` was used to put a window to the right half side of the screen. I configured it via `CompizConfig Settings Manager`.

I just upgraded my system to 11.10, all other customized shortcut keys keep working, except this `<Alt>Right`. Now it has the same functionality as `Alt+Tab`, so `swithing application`.

I have checked `CompizConfig Settings Manager`, which is still as before. And the `Shortcuts` list of `Keybord` setting, it seems that no one uses `<Alt>Right`.

Does anyone know what happened? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shortcut is assigned by default to the unity task switcher as 'Go right in the switcher'
To change this, you'll need to install CompizConfig Settings Manager, then in the Desktop section, find Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Select that, and the switcher tab. Select the shortcut, and disable it.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)