# How can I modify the icon size of the side main unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

How can I modify the icon size of the side main unity panel on ubuntu 11.10? I've tried installing the compiz configuration (ccsm), but it doesn't work. Maybe I didnt installed compiz correctly. Thanks!

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the *Ubuntu Software Center*
2. Search for *compizconfig*
3. You should see the *CompizConfig Settings Manager*, install it.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type '*ccsm*' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Once you have started *CompizConfig Settings Manager*, go to the *Desktop* category and click the *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*.
6. Click the *Experimental* tab and change the value of '*Launcher icon size*' setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CCSM you can find your answer here: [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903)

The other option is to use gconf-editor (which you will have to install) and then go to:

apps > compiz-1 > plugins > unityshell > screen0 > options and looks for the 'icon_size' option. You can change it there as well using values from 32 - 64.